# Cover an unplugged audio cord so it doesn't create a hum

Tags: speakers, setup, computer

When I have my laptop at my desk, I plug in my computer speakers to it. When I move it to my bed, I have another headphone cord that runs there, which is also plugged into the speakers. The problem is that when that first cord is sitting unplugged, but with the other end plugged into the speakers, it of course generates a considerable hum.

I notice the hum goes away when you plug it into any jack, which makes me wonder: is there some kind of jack-shaped "cover" one can put on it to stop the hum when you're not using it?

The alternative would be to unplug that wire from the speakers each time, which is inconvenient.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about home audio unrelated to a production concern.

Comment: Quick bone to throw you though, audio cables should not cause a buzz like this unless something is causing the pins to touch.

Comment: EDIT (THIS COMMENT BY Tetsujin) Whilst off-topic, it appears you've just discovered the age-old adage... "always unplug the other end first" which guitarists etc have known since the first amp was invented.